# Consume secured Web service in Classic ASP

Tags: web-services, iis, https, asp-classic

I am new to ASP classic and IIS. I have been given task to call a Web Service from Classic ASP. I have achieved that. The code I have written is as follows :

```
<%
On Error Resume Next
Dim oRequest
Set oRequest = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

' HTTP URL
msURL = "http://10.6.10.65:8080/myweb/hello"

'HTTPS URL
'msURL = "https://10.6.10.65:8443/myweb/hello" 


msSOAP = "<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ws=""http://ws.mkyong.com/"">"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "   <soapenv:Header/>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "   <soapenv:Body>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "      <ws:getHelloWorldAsString/>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "   </soapenv:Body>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</soapenv:Envelope>"


oRequest.Open "POST", msURL, False
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
oRequest.send msSOAP

Response.Clear
Response.BinaryWrite oRequest.responseBody

if err.number <> 0 then
    response.write "Error detected: " & err.number & ": " & err.Description & ""
    Response.end
end if

on error goto 0
%>
```

This is a simple Hello World web service.

The code works fine with http protocol to web service ("http://10.6.10.65:8080/myweb/hello") but When I change url of my web service to https ("https://10.6.10.65:8443/myweb/hello") I get follwing:

Error detected: -2147352571: 007~ASP 0106~Type Mismatch~An unhandled data type was encountered.

This is very vague error.. but I sense that I need to do something to get this work. 
The web service is on tomcat on different pc in network. I am having IIS 7.5 on windows server 2008. 
Please assist to get this work... I am in little mess

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try 
oRequest.setOption 2, 13056
after creating the object

Comment: Hi Balaji, Do you have any example regarding this? Thank you

Comment: No. Its a long time since i worked on ASP, but i vaguely remember this kind of situation that occurred and was resolved

Comment: I searched a bit and it worked.. I followed your suggestion, only change I made is, I used "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0" instead of  "Microsoft.XMLHTTP".. Thanks a lot for your quick reply Balaji!

Comment: Glad it helped you. :-)